# Sorting and searching problem related to a group of people standing in a rectangle

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions

Please be brutal, and let me know how I've done on this problem, provided I coded it at an interview for a top tech firm.

**Time it took me:** 44 minutes

**Worst case time complexity:** O(n<sup>2</sup>)?  Am I right?

**Space Complexity:** O(n)?

**Problem:**

> A group of people stand before you arranged in rows and columns.
>   Looking from above, they form an R by C rectangle of people. You will
>   be given a `String[]` people containing the height of each person.
>   Elements of people correspond to rows in the rectangle. Each element
>   contains a space-delimited list of integers representing the heights
>   of the people in that row.
>
> Your job is to return 2 specific heights in
>   a `int[]`. The first is computed by finding the shortest person in each
>   row, and then finding the tallest person among them (the
>   "tallest-of-the-shortest"). The second is computed by finding the
>   tallest person in each column, and then finding the shortest person
>   among them (the "shortest-of-the-tallest").

**Definition:**

> **Class:** `TallPeople`
>
> **Method:** `getPeople`
>
> **Parameters:** `String[]`
>
> **Returns:** `int[]`
>
> **Method signature:** `int[] getPeople(String[] people)` (be sure your method is public)
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - people will contain between 2 and 50 elements inclusive.
> - Each element of people will contain between 3 and 50 characters inclusive.
> - Each element of people will be a single space-delimited list of positive integers such that:
>
>   1. Each positive integer is between 1 and 1000 inclusive with no extra
>        leading zeros.
>   2. Each element contains the same number of integers.
>   3. Each element contains at least 2 positive integers.
>   4. Each element does not contain leading or trailing whitespace.

**Examples:**

> ```
> {"9 2 3",
>  "4 8 7"}
> ```
>
> Returns: { 4,  7 }
>
> The heights 2 and 4 are the shortest from the rows,
>   so 4 is the taller of the two. The heights 9, 8, and 7 are the tallest
>   from the columns, so 7 is the shortest of the 3. 1)
>
> ```
> {"1 2",
>  "4 5",
>  "3 6"}
> ```
>
> Returns: { 4,  4 }
>
> ```
> {"1 1",
>  "1 1"}
> ```
>
> Returns: { 1,  1 }

**Answer:**

```
public static int[] getPeople(String[] people){
    int maxOfMinHeight = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minOfMaxHeight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int count=0;

    String[][]findMaxOfMin = new String[people.length][people[0].split(" ").length];
    int[][] findMinOfMax = new int[people[0].split(" ").length][people.length];

    for(String s : people){
        String[] sort  = s.split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(sort);
        findMaxOfMin[count++]=sort;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<findMaxOfMin.length; i++){
        maxOfMinHeight = Math.max(maxOfMinHeight, Integer.valueOf(findMaxOfMin[i][0])); 
    }
    count=0;
    int cols = people[0].split(" ").length;
    for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
        int[] temp = new int[people.length];
        for(int j=0; j<people.length; j++){
            temp[j] = Integer.valueOf( ((String[])people[j].split(" "))[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(temp);
        findMinOfMax[count++]=temp;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<findMinOfMax.length; i++){
        minOfMaxHeight = Math.min(minOfMaxHeight, findMinOfMax[i][people.length-1]);
    }
    return new int[] {minOfMaxHeight, maxOfMinHeight};
}
```

Comment: From where do you get these problems? :)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg TopCoder. :) I have a major interview coming up in September, and I am preparing for it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Split it up!  The current method does more than one thing, I'd create at least three helper methods:

   ```
   int[][] parseInput(String[] input);
   int getMaxOfMinHeightInColumns(int[][] peoples);
   int getMinOfMaxHeightInRows(int[][] peoples);
   ```

   It would be easier to follow and understand.
2. I looks like a bug that the following testcase fails:

   ```
   @Test
   public void test() {
       String[] input = {"9 2 3",
        "4 8 7"};
       int[] result = getPeople(input);
       assertArrayEquals(new int[] {4, 7}, result);
   }
   ```
3. Reusing the count variable is a bad sing:

   > ```
   > count=0;
   > ```

   Try to use two different variables for different purposes and more descriptive names. What does it count? Put that into the name of the variable.
4. A few explanatory variable would be more readable here and remove some duplication:

   > ```
   > String[][]findMaxOfMin = new String[people.length][people[0].split(" ").length];
   > int[][] findMinOfMax = new int[people[0].split(" ").length][people.length];
   > ```

   Consider creating one for `people.length` and another for `people[0].split(" ").length` (columnNumber, rowNumber, for example).
5. `(String[])` casting seems unnecessary here:

   > ```
   > temp[j] = Integer.valueOf( ((String[])people[j].split(" "))[i]);
   > ```

Comment: what about the space complexity and time complexity of the problem I solved?

Comment: @bazang: Space complexity seems O(n). I can't say too much about time complexity I didn't understand the code completely.

Answer (score 3):

Complexity will essentially be defined by this structure:

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
>     int[] temp = new int[people.length];
>     for(int j=0; j<people.length; j++){
>         temp[j] = Integer.valueOf( ((String[])people[j].split(" "))[i]);
>     }
>     Arrays.sort(temp);
>     findMinOfMax[count++]=temp;
> }
> ```

which, using 'c' for `cols`, and 'p' for `people.length` will produce a complexity of:

- *O( p * c )* for the inner for-loop

  - the loop itself is is *O(p)* and
  - *O(c)* for the `((String[])people[j].split(" "))`
- *O(p log p)* for the `Arrays.sort(temp)`

Putting those together in the outer O(c) loop, I calculate the complexity to be in the order of:

***O( pc<sup>2</sup> + cp log p )***

The ***O(pc<sup>2</sup>)*** will be the dominant complexity.

If you move the Split to be outside the outer loop, and do something like:

```
int[][] data = new int[people.length][cols];
for (int j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
    String[] parts = people[j].split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        data[j][i] = Integer.valueOf(parts[i]);
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
    int[] temp = new int[people.length];
    for(int j=0; j<people.length; j++){
        temp[j] = data[j][i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(temp);
    findMinOfMax[count++]=temp;
}
```

Then your overall complexity will drop to ***O(pc log p)*** because that part of the complexity will bcome dominant.